# Component Doesn't Show Up & React JS

Tags: reactjs

There is a problem about my compenent, that is it doesn't show up? It's a first I'm doing a website project and using JS and React, so I don't know really what is the deal... I am even trying to learn by copying codes from tutorials, I always had done it like this before, when I wanted to learn something. But there is not an error or something and yet, it doesn't show up when I run the project at all.

Here is...

***App.js***

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import { CssBaseline, Container, Grid, AppBar, Toolbar, Typography, Button, IconButton } from "@material-ui/core";
import PenIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Create"
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route, Navigate} from "react-router-dom";
import PostsList from "./components/PostsList";
import AddPostForm from "./components/AddPostForm";
```

.
.
.

```
 <Routes>
            <Route exact path="/posts" element={<PostsList/>}/>
          </Routes>
```

and

***PostList.js***

```
import React from 'react'

const PostsList = () => {
  return <div>PostsList</div>
};

export default PostsList;
```

Edit: I added the part I used PostsList to App.js
And my problem solved when I exchange from "component" to "element" and add < /> sides of PostsList.

Comment: Could you please show us the complete code of **App.js**? You've imported a hell lot of things in App.js but the App component itself is missing.

Comment: Can you show me the render part of your App.js.
Atleast the part where you're using the <PostsList /> component.

Comment: Considering you edit note, you were probably copying code using react router 5 while you have react router 6 installed

Comment: Yes, It seems that was the case and even I saw element thing and tried before, since it wasn't working in that way either, I was just hopeless. Then I saw they also used {< />} this, and it solved.

Answer (score 1):

Use it like,

```
<Route exact path="/posts" component={PostsList} />
```

or

```
<Route exact path="/posts">
   <PostsList/>
</Route>
```

Answer (score 0):

You show us only the imports from you `App.js` file, but to render a component is not only import the file, but also write it between `return()`
Try to write in your App.js:

```
const App = () => {
    return(
        <div className="App">
            <PostLists />
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

that's because you just imported your components, you should display it in your `App.js` like below

```
const App = () => {
    return(
        <div className="App">
            <PostLists />
        </div>
    )
}
```